# Custom MessageConverter not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to register a custom `MessageConverter` in Spring Boot to give me more control over how messages gets converted. I have a Spring Boot 2.1.7 Webflux application.

I created my custom converter:

```
public class CustomConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
    ...
}
```

And registered it with:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new CustomConverter();
}
```

I also confirmed that it is registered by autowiring `HttpMessageConverters` and confirming that it is in the list of converters.
I then implemented a few methods I was expecting to be called like `canRead`, `canWrite`, `readInternal`, `writeInternal` and put breakpoints on them. 
My application exposes an Rest endpoint which responds with JSON and also calls an external Rest service which POST a JSON payload and receives JSON in return.

At no point can I see that my converter is being used. I even removed all other converters, leaving just my own but it is still not being called.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my WebFlux application, I had to do the following to get it working:

```
@Bean
public WebFluxConfigurer webFluxConfigurer(){

    return new WebFluxConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.registerDefaults(false);
            configurer.customCodecs().encoder(new CustomEncoder());
            configurer.customCodecs().decoder(new CustomDecoder());
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: This worked for me, so many other incorrect solutions

Answer (score 0):

In case it is Controller argument you want to convert, use the `@RequestBody` annotation to indicate that the body of the HTTP Request is deserialized to that particular Java entity.

To determine the appropriate converter, Spring will use the “Content-Type” and "Accept" header from the client request.

So the below request will be handled by JSON converter (and not xml converter), because of the "Accept: application/json"

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json"
  http://localhost:8080/spring-boot-rest/foos/1
```

"Accept" specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response. 
"Content-Type" indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the server.

For more cases, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest)